# Adding border and Rounded Rect in the NSView

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview

In my Application , NSView should have rounded rect and border, i tried following

```
static CGColorRef CGColorCreateFromNSColor (CGColorSpaceRef
                                            colorSpace, NSColor *color)
{
    NSColor *deviceColor = [color colorUsingColorSpaceName:
                            NSDeviceRGBColorSpace];

    float components[4];
    [deviceColor getRed: &components[0] green: &components[1] blue:
     &components[2] alpha: &components[3]];

    return CGColorCreate (colorSpace, components);
}
```

and in InitWithframe added following lines of Code

```
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:505];
    [[self layer] setBorderWidth:500.0];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB ();
    CGColorRef cgColor = CGColorCreateFromNSColor (colorSpace, [NSColor whiteColor]);
    CGColorSpaceRelease (colorSpace);
    [[self layer] setBorderColor:cgColor];
```

but no effects at all, is there any other method,

Another approach what i could guess is , in drawRect draw border and but it seems very complex, can anyone suggest me any other method

Kind Regards

Rohan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for looking at this, this logic worked for me,

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
   if([self hasBorder])
    [self drawBorder:rect];

}

-(void)drawBorder:(NSRect)rect{
    NSRect frameRect = [self bounds];

    if(rect.size.height < frameRect.size.height) 
        return;
    NSRect newRect = NSMakeRect(rect.origin.x+2, rect.origin.y+2, rect.size.width-3, rect.size.height-3);

    NSBezierPath *textViewSurround = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:newRect xRadius:10 yRadius:10];
    [textViewSurround setLineWidth:BORDER_WIDTH];
    [pBorderColor set];
    [textViewSurround stroke];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For the layer properties to have any affect you need to set setWantsLayer on your NSView to YES first.

I have this in InitWithFrame for my view:

```
[self setWantsLayer: YES];
[self.layer setBorderWidth: 2];
[self.layer setCornerRadius: 10];
```

Answer (score 0):

A little enhancement to the previous answer. If you don't want to subclass your NSView if it's the base view of your controller you can also do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.wantsLayer = true
    }
```